# What does vertex:disp and tessellate:tessEdge mean? [Shader] [Unity]

Tags: unity, shaders, hlsl, cg

I came across the following declaration on unity tutorial

```
#pragma surface surf BlinnPhong addshadow fullforwardshadows 
vertex:disp tessellate:tessEdge nolightmap
```

I think disp is the displacement shader but what does `vertex:disp` mean?
Likewise for `tesselate:tessEdge`.

from https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaderTessellation.html

Thanks. I am rather new to HLSL.

Comment: if you don't use it your vertex function not work any way.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali. What do you mean by `vertex function`? You mean vertex shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vertex shader**

> It is possible to use a “vertex modifier” function that will modify the incoming vertex data in the vertex Shader. This can be used for things like procedural animation and extrusion along normals. Surface Shader compilation directive vertex:functionName is used for that, with a function that takes inout appdata_full parameter.
>
> https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaderExamples.html

your vertex modifier function named `disp`.

so `vertex:disp` mean that your `vertex` will use `disp`:

```
void disp (inout appdata v)
{
float d = tex2Dlod(_DispTex, float4(v.texcoord.xy,0,0)).r * _Displacement;
v.vertex.xyz += v.normal * d;
}
```

**[DX11 Tessellation](https://www.nvidia.com/object/tessellation.html)**

[image]

This controls how many subdivisions you want to split your triangles into. (Note that DirectX is Windows only, requires a DX11 GPU and has to be enabled in Unity)

so `tesselate:tessEdge` mean that your `tesselatation` will use `tessEdge`:

```
float4 tessEdge (appdata_full v0, appdata_full v1, appdata_full v2)
{
return UnityEdgeLengthBasedTess (v0.vertex, v1.vertex, v2.vertex, _EdgeLength);
}
```

If you want to understand tesselatation use `Shading Mode > WireFrame` then move around your object that has this shader:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response Seyed Morteza Kamali.